# RecyclerView OnClick Method

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I implemented RecyclerView List and whenever I click on something in the list, the app crashes.

Here's the code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Intent intent;
            switch (getAdapterPostion()) {
                case 0:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, TestingActivity.class);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, TestingActivity.class);

                    break;

                case 2:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, TestingActivity.class);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, TestingActivity.class);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, TestingActivity.class);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, TestingActivity.class);
                    break;

                default:
                    intent =  new Intent(context, Timeline.class);
                    break;
            }
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private int getAdapterPostion() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: post error log .

Comment: Minor edits for legibility and code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Use holder.getAdapterPosition() instead. And Please put the click listener in viewHolder, not in BindViewHolder. BindViewHolder calls every time when we call, notifyDatasetChanged() and also when we scrolling down. It affects the app's performance. Let me know for any query. All the best.

Comment: Hello Krunal Kapadiya,

thank you for your very quick answer. To be honest I'm trying to implement a RecyclerView List that can open new activities on click. I think my whole code is wrong. Could you help me how I can do that? I use NavigationDrawer that call specific fragments on click (First, Second and Third Fragment) In First Fragment I want to create this RecyclerView List that calls another activities. It's been fifth day I'm looking for good tutorial but without any results. Can I consultate this with you please?